# Can you have MsTests and Windows-forms functional tests live in the same project file?

Tags: winforms, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I've been asked to investigate the possibility of using a single .csproj file to run both interactive and unit tests. I've been able to get the windows forms project changed over to run msTests but now I'm not finding a way to run the windows forms/interactive side. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 methods I've found for what my team was looking for. `nUnit` instead of `MsTests`, or manually executing the `/debug` built win-forms executable and then attaching the debugger to it. So nice clean integration using MsTests/VS2010 is out the window.